# How to capture the longest match of a repeating pattern using BASH_REMATCH

Tags: bash, regex-group

I am trying to capture the longest match of a repeating pattern

```
do_run() {
    local regex='.*((abc)+).*'
    local str='_abcabcabc123_'

    echo "regex=${regex}"$'\n'
    echo "str=${str}"$'\n'

    if [[ "${str}" =~ ${regex} ]]
    then
        for i in ${!BASH_REMATCH[@]}
        do
            echo "$i=${BASH_REMATCH[i]}"
        done
    else
        echo "no match"
    fi
}
```

I get the following output :

```
regex=.*((abc)+).*
str=_abcabcabc_
0=_abcabcabc123_
1=abc
2=abc
```

I am trying to get something like :

```
regex=.*((abc)+).*
str=_abcabcabc123_
0=_abcabcabc123_
x=abcabcabc
```

(Update : `x` is just here to indicate that the index of the matching group does not matter but I need to know what number to use to retrieve the matching group ...)

**Update:**

[After reading comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66022130/how-to-capture-the-longest-match-of-a-repeating-pattern-using-bash-rematch#comment116730264_66022130), the following regex will work : `((abc)+)`

However, I also need to capture what precedes and what follows `((abc)+)`.

I had not mentionned it earlier because I thought the same solution would be applied.

So the new code would be :

```
do_run() {
    local regex='(.*)((abc)+)(.*)'
    local str='_abcabcabc123_'

    echo "regex=${regex}"$'\n'
    echo "str=${str}"$'\n'

    if [[ "${str}" =~ ${regex} ]]
    then
        for i in ${!BASH_REMATCH[@]}
        do
            echo "$i=${BASH_REMATCH[i]}"
        done
    else
        echo "no match"
    fi
}
```

I get then the following output :

```
regex=(.*)((abc)+)(.*)
str=_abcabcabc123_
0=_abcabcabc123_
1=_abcabc
2=abc
3=abc
4=123_
```

I want to be able to retrieve `abcabcabc` from a matching group but also what precedes it and what follows it

Comment: You may use regex as `((abc)+)`

Comment: @anubhava : x is just here to indicate that the index of the matching group does not matter but I need to know what number to use to retrieve the matching group.  

Also, I have updated the question, to indicate that I also need to be able to retrieve what precedes and what follows ((abc+))

Comment: You just need to grab `"${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"`

Comment: @anubhava : Thank you for your help ! Yes, "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" will work if I use ((abc)+) but I cannot just use ((abc)+) as regex, because I also need to capture what precedes and what follows ((abc)+)  : see updated part of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround you can do like this:

```
[STEP 101] $ cat foo.sh
v=_abcabcabc123_
if [[ $v =~ (abc)+ ]]; then
    middle=${BASH_REMATCH[0]}

    [[ $v =~ (.*)"$middle" ]]
    before=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}

    [[ $v =~ "$middle"(.*) ]]
    after=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}

    echo "before: $before"
    echo "middle: $middle"
    echo "after : $after"
fi
[STEP 102] $ bash foo.sh
before: _
middle: abcabcabc
after : 123_
[STEP 103] $
```

Comment: @anubhava no, `$middle` is double quoted and that part will not be handled as RE. according to `man bash`: "Any part of the pattern may be quoted to **force the quoted portion to be matched as a string.**"

Comment: It fixed my problem. Thank you ! I have voted for your answer because it does not use external tools, and is easier to reuse if abc should be replaced by a long string.

Answer (score 1):

> I also need to capture what precedes and what follows ((abc)+).

For that, typically you'll need a negative lookahead  with perl regex, something along `(?<!abc)((abs)+)(.*)`.

I am bad at perl regex, with perl-enabled `grep` I was able to this:

```
$ grep -oxP '(.*)(?<!abc)((abc)+)\K(.*)' <<<'_abcabcabc123_'
123_
$ grep -oP '((abc)+)' <<<'_abcabcabc123_'
abcabcabc
$ rev  <<<'_abcabcabc123_' | grep -oP '(.*)(?<!cba)((cba)+)\K(.*)' | rev
_
```

Bash has no lookarounds and no perl regex. Consider using python or perl.

But you may use sed by splitting the part on the regex and then reading lines, which may be simpler:

```
$ readarray -t lines < <(<<<'_abcabcabc123_' sed -E 's/((abc)+)/\n&\n/'); declare -p lines
declare -a lines=([0]="_" [1]="abcabcabc" [2]="123_")
```

Another idea: you may use bash expansion to replace the `abc` parts by something unique, then split it on that separator:

```
$ IFS=' ' read -r before post < <(printf "%s\n" "${str//abc/ }") ; declare -p before post
declare -- before="_"
declare -- post="123_"
# or
$ IFS='@' read -r before post < <(<<<"${str//abc/@}" tr -s '@') ; declare -p before post
declare -- before="_"
declare -- post="123_"
```

Answer (score 1):

For your given input this regex would work:

```sh
re='^([^a]|a[^b]*|ab[^c]*)((abc)+)(.*)'
str='_abcabcabc123_'
[[ $str =~ $re ]] && declare -p BASH_REMATCH
```

**Output:**

```
declare -ar BASH_REMATCH=([0]="_abcabcabc123_" [1]="_" [2]="abcabcabc" [3]="abc" [4]="123_")
```

So you can use:

```sh
"${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" # string before
"${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" # string containing all "abc"s
"${BASH_REMATCH[4]}" # string after
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nAygBU/1/)

Comment: tried `re='^([^a]|a[^b]|ab[^c])*((abc)+)(.*)'; [[ aabcabcabc123_ =~ $re ]] && declare -p BASH_REMATCH` and got `declare -a BASH_REMATCH=([0]="aabcabcabc123_" [1]="c" [2]="abcabc" [3]="abc" [4]="123_")`

Comment: and this kind of solution does not scale well. :)

Comment: `re='^([^a]|a[^b]*|ab[^c]*)((?:abc)+)(.*)'` -- does bash not support `(?:...)`?

Comment: yes of course `(?:...)` is not supported, it was a bad copy/paste from demo site. Thanks